# Is my as-simple-as-possible connection manager in java thread-safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, datasource, connection-pooling

I try to create a as-simple-as-possible connection manager för a small web-application that runs on a tomcat7 server. I have found many examples of how to implement this, but almost always those requires JNDI and JEE, or else there are no complete example.

I want my connection manager to deliver a connection from a connection-pool when I call getConnection(), and that it is thread-safe so that no other uses my connection until I close it.

In my application I call ConnectionManager.getConnection() from a REST-service and then use that connection for all database-calls throughout the request, and close it in a finally-clause.

Could someone please look at my code and see if it is good enough to fullfill my needs...? Is it any risk that two REST-calls could get the same connection or does the tomcat DataSource handle that for me?

Would it be more proper to make my class a DataSourceManager with a getDataSource() method that deliver the data source, and in my REST-service get a connection with DataSourceManager.getDataSource().getConnection()? Would it make any difference, technically?

Or do I have to do this in an other way to make it work properly...?

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties;

import se.esvenska.util.Property;

public class ConnectionManager {

    private static DataSource dataSource;

    private static void initDataSource() throws DatabaseException {
        try {
            PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
            p.setUrl("...url...");
            p.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            p.setUsername("...user...");
            p.setPassword("...password...");
            p.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);

            dataSource = new DataSource();
            dataSource.setPoolProperties(p);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new DatabaseException(e);
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        if (dataSource == null) {
            initDataSource();
        }
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is. I use a similar one for years already (it looks like a copy paste of the Tomcat manual anyway)

Comment: Your `getConnection()` is snot thread safe as the `dataSource` could be `null` for multiple requests at the same time. You can easily fix this (without the need for locking) by putting `initDataSource` into the initialiser for the `datasource` field. I dont know the postgresql driver well, so I cannot say how good its pool is (especially in regards to validation and resource leak tracking).

Comment: Thanks for comments! @eckes: would moving the initialization of the dataSource to the constructor do the trick?

Comment: In this case no constructor is used, it is a monostate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by thread-safe. I don't think it'll blow up, but there's definitely the chance that you'll call `initDataSource` more than once.

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    if (dataSource == null) {          // Another thread can come in after this
        initDataSource();              // and before this
    }
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}
```

You'll need to `synchronize` that method:

```
public static synchronized Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
// -----------^
    if (dataSource == null) {          // Now this region is
        initDataSource();              // protected
    }
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend couple of changes:

- Make constructor private
- `getConnection` should be thread safe using double locking, detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

  ```
  package com.test;

  import java.sql.Connection;

  import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
  import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties;

  import se.esvenska.util.Property;

  public class ConnectionManager {

  private ConnectionManager() {
  }

  private static DataSource dataSource;

  private static void initDataSource() throws DatabaseException {
      try {
          PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
          p.setUrl("...url...");
          p.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
          p.setUsername("...user...");
          p.setPassword("...password...");
          p.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);

          dataSource = new DataSource();
          dataSource.setPoolProperties(p);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          throw new DatabaseException(e);
      }
  }

  public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
      if (dataSource == null) {
          synchronized(ConnectionManager. class) {
              if (dataSource == null) {
                  initDataSource();
              }
          }
      }
      return dataSource.getConnection();
  }
  }
  ```